# Ubuntu 12.10 no network and no graphics

Tags: wireless, 12.10, network-manager, toshiba-satellite

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 only to find out that it won't connect to any network, neither wired nor wireless and the graphics is messed up too as in a low screen resolution.

For 12.04, my system was running perfectly. I don't know why upgrade messed it up so bad. Reinstalling the OS is an issue because I have set up a lot of development environments that I cannot afford to set it up again.

Some of the outputs:

`lspci -nn | grep 0200`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

`nm-tool`:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n20`:

```
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (-1240454760) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt bluetoothd[1016]: Failed to init network plugin
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> modem-manager is now available
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt kernel: [   28.688167] type=1400 audit(1351882222.452:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1046 comm="apparmor_parser"
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt bluetoothd[1062]: Failed to init network plugin
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt bluetoothd[1118]: Failed to init network plugin
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt bluetoothd[1237]: Failed to init network plugin
Nov  2 13:50:22 Cobalt NetworkManager[978]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

`ps aux | grep -i network`:

```
root       978  0.0  0.1  23732  4808 ?        Ssl  13:50   0:00 NetworkManager
```

`sudo modprobe -r forcedeth`:

```
FATAL: Module forcedeth not found
```

Comment: for anyone reading this now, try redoing the install, use apt-key to backup your installed software so you can reinstall it with one command. move your home directory temporarily and then back after the install, this will protect all your settings, etc. This is the only way you can get around a bad install while not losing your installed software/settings. I've had problems with 12.04->12.10 myself and i would suggest anyone else to stick with the LTS versions unless you MUST upgrade often, this seems to be a good rule: "if it ain't broke, dont fix it, especially when it comes to ubuntu!!!!!!"

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

As I found, following these instructions and giving the machine a restart fixes the wireless adapter. DON'T go installing the Broadcom proprietary drivers through System Settings, Additional Drivers, or you'll just reset the whole lot back to the non-working ones!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me but I just run the update manager again without attaching my cables or the mobile broadband. The **Update Manager** tells me there is update available downloaded but not installed, I then click on install and reboot the machine. Everything is working fine. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar experience than Adil Elsir.

I did a dist upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. At the end of the process it mentioned that some errors happened. I had a look but found nothing useful, so rebooted. Then the same symptoms started: VGA mode, no network. Also `sudo restart networking` crashed the desktop.

So I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which prompted me that something was wrong and I should try to force install, so I did `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`, then rebooted a few times. Once again I tried to upgrade and he tells me there is more package that were "kept back". Most notably linux-image-generic (!). `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` told me that I was running 3.2 and 3.5 could be installed. So I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and that went rather well.

However on reboot I got a kernel panic (not my day). But rebooting again and selecting kernel 3.2 in grub allowed to actually log in in my desktop with normal graphics and networking. Yay !

tl;dr keep upgrading whatever you can via `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`